# Integratin validation rules with ajax

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

im using for the first time ajax with laravel validation, but im having some problems in how to integrate the to of them, how can i communicate my laravel validation code with my ajax? I have in my javascript some validation rules where each number is a rule, how can i integrate it with my laravel? 
There is a example of my code:

laravel Controller function:

```
 public function saveEmail(Request $request)
    {

        $user = Auth::user();
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'current_email'     => 'required|email|exists:users,email,id,'. $user->id,
            'email'             => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'verify_password'   => 'required'
        ));


        //Verify information user before updating
        if($user->email != $request->current_email){
            dd("Current Email is not the same");
        }

        if(! Hash::check($request->verify_password, $user->password)){
            dd("Password incorrect, will not update");
        }


        //Update Email with Sucess
        $user->email =  $request->email;



    }
```

Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#saveEmail").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                saveEmail();
            });

        });

 function saveEmail() {

            var email = $("#current_email").val();
            var new_email = $("#email").val();
            var password = $("#verify_password").val();
            var data = { current_email: email, email: new_email, verify_password: password }
            $.ajax({
                url: "company/saveEmail')}}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == 0) {
                     //Email saved correctlly
                     var text = 'E-mail actualizado';
                     $('#saveOK').text(text);
                     $("#current_email").val("");
                     $("#email").val("");
                     $("#password").val("");
                     $("#ErrorEmail").css({ "display": "none" });
                     }
                     else if (result == 1) {
                     //"Incomplete data"
                     var error1 = 'The data are incomplete';
                     $("#lbtxtEmailError").text(error1);
                     $("#ErrorEmail").css({ "display": "block" });
                     }
                     else if (result == 2) {
                     //"Current email incorrect"
                     var error2 = 'Current email is incorrect';
                     $("#lbtxtEmailError").text(error2);
                     $("#ErrorEmail").css({ "display": "block" });
                     }
                     else if (result == 3) {
                     //"Incorrect format"
                     var error3 = 'The format is incorrect';
                     $("#lbtxtEmailError").text(error3);
                     $("#ErrorEmail").css({ "display": "block" });
                     }
                     else if (result == 4) {
                     //This email is already in use
                     var error4 = 'This email is already in use';
                     $("#lbtxtEmailError").text(error4);
                     $("#ErrorEmail").css({ "display": "block" });
                     }
                     else if (result == 5) {
                     //"Current password incorrect";
                     var error5 = 'Your password is incorrect';
                     $("#lbtxtEmailError").text(error5);
                     $("#ErrorEmail").css({ "display": "block" });
                     }
                     else if (result == 6) {
                     //"This user doesnt exist" id
                     var error6 = 'User doesnt exist';
                     $("#lbtxtEmailError").text(error6);
                     $("#ErrorEmail").css({ "display": "block" });
                     }
                     else if (result == 7) {
                     //"New email already exist"
                     var error7 = 'New email alreadu exist ';
                     $("#lbtxtEmailError").text(error7);
                     $("#ErrorEmail").css({ "display": "block" });
                     }

                }

            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One important distinction to make about validation requests between a normal threaded request and an ajax request is how the validator will respond in the event of failure. From the documentation, this is how the response is crafted (upon failure):

> If the incoming request was an ajax request, no redirect will be generated. Instead, an HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the browser containing a JSON representation of the validation errors.

A 422 is great, because this means we can observe failures within the `.error()` callback of the promise.

```
$.ajax({
    //routes, urls, data, etc
}).done(function(response){
    //this all worked well
}).error(function(data){
    //walk the object for your data
    console.warn(data);
});
```

Also, Taylor has warned about `fat controllers`. We should try to use abstracted logic wherever possible. Instead, we should make a proper `Request`

```
php artisan make:request SaveEmailRequest
```

Then open up our file at `App\Http\Requests\SaveEmailRequest` and locate the `public function authorize()` function. Here we will check to see if the user's email and the request email match:

```
/**
 * @returns boolean
 */
public function authorize()
{
    $flag = isset($this->current_email) && $this->current_email == auth()->user()->email);
    $flag = Hash::check($this->verify_password, auth()->user()->password);

    return $flag;
}
```

Then we can move our rules into the `public function rules()` of our request now:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'current_email'     => 'required|email|exists:users,email,id,'. auth()->user()->id,
        'email'             => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'verify_password'   => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Finally we just need to use this in our controller:

```
public function saveEmail(App\Http\Requests\SaveEmailRequest $request) 
{
    auth()->user()->update([
        'email' => $request->email
    ]);
}
```

You'll notice we don't return anything above. That's because we don't need to. The response will come back as `200` which will get into the `.done()` function of our promise. We don't have to worry about guessing.

If any failures happen (hash check, email doesn't match, password doesn't match), then the `422` response will be returned and the error messages can be found in the `data` argument of our `.error()` method.

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: thanks for the response it was really helpfull, one last question, on the Authorize function it doesnt recognize $user or $request, is sayns variable undefined, do i have to create it the begining of authorize function? Isnt suppose already be defined? Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: @Pedro Glad it helped! I've updated the answer, `$user` was not set and was only  due to a copy + paste. It should be `auth()->user()`. Please see the edit above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the help, but i still having same issue with the "$request" variable, do i need to put in the authorize() the Request $request ?

Comment: @Pedro Sorry for the delay. In the New `SaveEmailRequest` that **is** the request, so you reference it with  `$this->` instead of `$request`. Answer updated. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, i just updated the code but after i submit just to test is giving me a message "Forbidden 403"

Comment: @pedro The `authorize` function has failed in that case. Use `dd($flag)` to see what it's returning and then test to see why there's a failure.

Comment: Is returning False.

Comment: @Pedro Well the logic here needs to be walked through, try making sure variables are set, check the one line after another; etc. Eventually you'll find it:)